# Remove key value from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my db result,

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [shopname] => Shop name [fueltype] => Pertol [amount] => 1000 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [shopname] => dfsdfsd [fueltype] => Pertol [amount] => 54456 )
       [2] => Array ( [shopname] => dfsdfsd [fueltype] => Disel [amount] => 54456 )
)
```

I need result like

```
[["Shop name", "Pertol", 1000],["dfsdfsd", "Pertol", 54456],["Shop name", "Disel", 54456]]
```

How to get like this, I have no idea?

Comment: First do a conversion from key value to value only (`array_values()`) and then a `json_encode()`... Those are your friends now... ;)

Comment: Ajin it's your responsibility to check answers and mark one answer which is most suitable to you. It will help future visitors to find out solution easily.Thanks.(You can up-vote others too if they are useful)

Answer (score 3):

`array_map()` along with `array_values()` will work for you:-

```
<?php
$array = Array ( '0' => Array ( 'shopname' => 'Shop name','fueltype' => 'Pertol','amount' => 1000 ), 
        '1' => Array ( 'shopname' => 'dfsdfsd' ,'fueltype' => 'Pertol','amount' => 54456 ),
        '2' => Array ( 'shopname' => 'dfsdfsd','fueltype' => 'Disel','amount' => 54456 )
);


$values_data_only = array_map('array_values', $array);
$desire_result = json_encode($values_data_only);
echo $desire_result;

?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/395344

Also via simple `foreach()` it is possible:-

```
<?php
$array = Array ( '0' => Array ( 'shopname' => 'Shop name','fueltype' => 'Pertol','amount' => 1000 ), 
        '1' => Array ( 'shopname' => 'dfsdfsd' ,'fueltype' => 'Pertol','amount' => 54456 ),
        '2' => Array ( 'shopname' => 'dfsdfsd','fueltype' => 'Disel','amount' => 54456 )
);

$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $k=> $arr){
    $new_array[$k][] = $arr['shopname'];
    $new_array[$k][] = $arr['fueltype'];
    $new_array[$k][] = $arr['amount'];
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
$desired_result_2 = json_encode($new_array);
echo $desired_result_2;
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/395354

Answer (score 2):

```
$mapped = array_map('array_values', $input_array); // apply filter so we dont get the keys
$json = json_encode($mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your input data */ );
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $data) {
  $output[] = array_values($data);
}
```

Comment: I think you dont need to initialize `$output`, outside foreach, it will save you a line of code !

Comment: @Viral That's a bad idea.