# PHP - MySql Query result format change

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Model:**

```
function traceability(){
        $query=$this->db->query("select coalesce(bp.stock_deduct, 1) as stock_deduct, bp.grn_id, p.part_id 
from (
    select 34 as part_id, 1 as seq
    union all select 8, 2
    union all select 36, 3
    union all select 436, 4
    union all select 6, 5
    
) p
left join planning_part_list b on b.part_id = p.part_id and b.batch_id = '0' and b.sr_no = '23' 
left join bom_part_assign bp on bp.bom_id = b.id
order by p.seq");
return $query->result_array();
    }
```

MySql Query Result:

[image]

**Controller:**

```
$test['testing'] = $this->My_model->traceability();
$this->load->view('test',$test);
```

**View:**

```
<?php print_r($testing);?>
```

**which is printing as :**

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [stock_deduct] => 1 [grn_id] => 6 [part_id] => 34 
   ) 
   [1] => Array (
      [stock_deduct] => 2 [grn_id] => 9 [part_id] => 34 
   ) 
   [2] => Array ( 
      [stock_deduct] => 3 [grn_id] => GRN1 [part_id] => 34 
   ) 
   [3] => Array ( 
      [stock_deduct] => 1 [grn_id] => [part_id] => 8 
   ) 
   [4] => Array ( 
      [stock_deduct] => 1 [grn_id] => [part_id] => 6 
   ) 
);
```

**I need to print the $testing variable in view in below format:**

```
$testing = [
    [ 1, "6",  "34"],
    [ 2, "9",  "34"],
    [ 3, "GRN1",  "34"],
    [ 1, "", "8"],
    [ 1, "", "6"]
];
```

The existing view has a foreach that works like that so I need the array in the showed format for it to work.

```
$table_data = []; 
foreach($testing as $item){ 
   for($i = 0; $i < $item[0]; $i++){ 
      $table_data[$item[2]][] = $item[1]; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: The array is in that format, the only difference is that the array has naming indexes instead of numbers. May I ask why do you need the array like that? It's much more easy to access the items in the array with $testing[0][stock_deduct] than $testing[0][0].

Comment: @marcogmonteiro yes, I don't want to show the naming indexes and need to display the same format as mentioned in the question. Please help if you know how to do!

Comment: Because I want to execute the below code based on the structure mentioned in the question.

Comment: $table_data = [];

foreach($testing as $item){
    for($i = 0; $i < $item[0]; $i++){
        $table_data[$item[2]][] = $item[1];
    }
}

Comment: @marcogmonteiro Can we execute the above mentioned foreach with the existing structure? When I do I'm getting error.

Comment: Found the answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311250/remove-key-value-from-array-in-php